# How do I locate a specific digit

Tags: c#

I am trying to create 7 BOOM game. if you don't know the rules, everyone takes turns and says the next number but if the number can be divided by seven or contain seven you should say BOOM instead. so in my version, you insert a number and the program should show you all the numbers to that point.

So here is my problem, I succeeded in implementing the first part but I am having a problem with the second one. This is what I have until now:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int num2 = 0;
        bool boolean;
        while (num1>num2)
        {
            num2++;
            if (num2%7 == 0)
            {
                Console.Write("BOOM, ");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write(num2 + ", ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your validation to:

```
if (num2%7 == 0 || num2.ToString().IndexOf('7') != -1)
{
  // (..)
}
```

The [`IndexOf`](http://csharp.net-informations.com/string/csharp-string-indexof.htm) function looks for and returns the position of a substring in a string. If it is not found, it returns -1.

As pointed by @Dimitry, another option is

```
if (num2%7 == 0 || num2.ToString().Contains('7'))
{
  // (..)
}
```

This uses the extension method [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) that returns true or false if the substring exists on the string.

Comment: Side note: `num2.ToString().Contains('7')` is more readable implementation

Comment: You are right, I edited the answer. I thought Contains was a method in System.Lynq, I didn't remember it was an extension on string too.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.Write("Please enter a number: ");
    int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    // validate number here....

    for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
    {
        string value = IsMultipleOrContains7(i) ? "BOOM" : i.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static bool IsMultipleOrContains7(int number)
{
    if (number % 7 == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return number.ToString().Contains("7");
}
```

Comment: I think you missed the rule that the number can't contain the number 7.

Comment: Ooops you're completely right, thanks @itsme86. I'll fix it soon